# How to delete specific object under document in DocumentDB?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I am using documentDB as backend for my project.
I have created a collection named ResellerCollection.
Under it I added document as Reseller with Id's assign to it.
Now under Reseller document I have added a list of Customer and now I wanted to delete customer of reseller document by specific Id.

My JSON generated in documentDB is as follow.

```
{
"id": "73386791-5895-4a56-9108-df4a773331fe",
"Name": "Nadeem",
"PrimaryContact": "1234",
"Address": "bhusari clny",
"City": "pune",
"State": "maharashtra",
"Country": "india",
"ZipCode": "222",
"Telephone": "45234343",
"Email": "abc@xyz.com",
"Website": "asdfsd.com",
"Customer": [
  {
    "id": "4acf3ca9-f9e4-4117-a471-7ce8f905baec",
    "FullName": "Test Cust1",
    "Company": "safds",
    "JobTitle": "sadf",
    "Email": "abcd@xyz.com",
    "Address": "asdfsaf",
    "City": "sdf",
    "State": "sdf",
    "Country": "sadf",
    "ZipCode": "2343",
    "Telephone": "45234343",
    "MerchantID": "232",
    "IdentificationNo": "2342343",
    "IsActive": true,
    "CustomerGroupID": "34",
    "ResellerID": "73386791-5895-4a56-9108-df4a773331fe"
  },
  {
    "id": "e0d6d099-3d5d-4776-9b84-14b7ae0b9911",
    "FullName": "Test Cust2",
    "Company": "safds",
    "JobTitle": "sadf",
    "Email": "abcd@xyz.com",
    "Address": "asdfsaf",
    "City": "sdf",
    "State": "sdf",
    "Country": "sadf",
    "ZipCode": "2343",
    "Telephone": "sadf",
    "MerchantID": "232",
    "IdentificationNo": "2342343",
    "IsActive": true,
    "CustomerGroupID": "34",
    "ResellerID": "73386791-5895-4a56-9108-df4a773331fe"
  }
],
  "UserId": "f807f027-2e21-45b1-b786-e4d2b3d677cb",
  "_rid": "+JBQAOQWHQENAAAAAAAAAA==",
  "_self": "dbs/+JBQAA==/colls/+JBQAOQWHQE=/docs/+JBQAOQWHQENAAAAAAAAAA==/",
  "_etag": "\"0a004764-0000-0000-0000-583bd8b50000\"",
  "_attachments": "attachments/",
  "_ts": 1480317104
}
```

Please suggest me how to write delete function for customer in MVC. Whether I should write delete for it to delete specific customer or whether I have to update the whole customer list?

Comment: Not really related to your question but... you should know that you have an *unbounded array* condition in your data model (storing a potentially unlimited number of customers as an array within your reseller documents). This is exacerbated by the fact you're storing full information about each customer, vs, say, just a customer ID.

Comment: Thank you david, Larry and Aravind for your suggestions and it is really helpful for me..

Answer (score 1):

The only way to delete an element of an array (or any other change to the document) is to fetch the entire document, modify it, then create/upsert the entire document. You can do this client-side or in a stored procedure.

Try not to think of collections as tables in traditional databases or collections in MongoDB. I used to say, think of them as "partitions" but with partitioned collections, even that distinction is not useful. I use a single partitioned collection for everything now. I distinguish document types by having an element in each document: `isReseller = true` or `isCustomer = true` for your example. Alternatively, you can do `type = 'Reseller'` or `type = 'Customer'`. However, if the customer of one reseller is ever a reseller themselves, the former will allow you to add both `is___ = true` and the latter will not.

What David Makogon says is definitely a worry. Unless Resellers are restricted to a small number of Customers, you are better off storing them separately and having a foreign key link them. That way, deleting or adding one is a single step. However, getting the Reseller and all its Customers will be two round trips.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of doing this.

- Implement "AddCustomer" and "RemoveCustomer" stored procedures in DocumentDB. These stored procedures will read the reseller document, then append or remove the new customer passed in as argument. Then just call ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync within your controller.
- Instead of the stored procedure approach, perform three steps within the controller. Read the document, make changes, and replace the document.

In both implementations, you'll probably want to use the ETag to perform a conditional write to avoid any clobbering across multiple clients/writers.

As Larry and David pointed out, you should also consider different JSON modeling options such as storing the customers data as separate documents, or by storing only the IDs within the array vs. all relevant customer data.